# download file from ftp python

Tags: python, ftp

There's a file on this ftp server called `ftp://ftp.nass.usda.gov/quickstats/qs.crops_20210805.txt.gz`

(the date will usually be today's date in the same format, on weekends and it will be the previous Friday)

How can I use python to list files and download the one that has `crops_` in the url?

I tried doing this:

```
from ftplib import FTP
  
global ftp
ftp = FTP("ftp.nass.usda.gov")
ftp.login
ftp.retrlines('LIST')
```

But it's asking me to login with user/pw (shouldn't be needed) and if I change the site to `"ftp.nass.usda.gov/quickstats/"` (the dir where that file is located) I get:

> gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not properly calling `ftp.login`. You need to have the parenthesis at the end to do the anonymous login and execute the function, otherwise you're just returning the function without calling it
change

```
ftp.login
```

to

```
ftp.login()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from ftplib import FTP
  
global ftp
ftp = FTP("ftp.nass.usda.gov")
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd('quickstats')
list = ftp.nlst()
for _ in list:
    if 'crops' in _:
        print(_)
```

That should get you started. Jesse was correct you were missing ()